# Rails 3 remote stops working when I remove gon

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was using [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) with my project, but decided I didn't want it anymore.

With gon, `application.html.erb` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield :title) %></title>
  <%= include_gon %>
  <%= render 'layouts/stylesheets' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>

  <!-- Begin Analytics -->
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-29558757-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

  </script>
 <!-- End Analytics -->

  <!-- Begin favicon.ico -->
  <%= favicon_link_tag %>
  <!-- End facicon.ico -->

</head>
<body>
  <% unless @home  %>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  <% end %>

  <div id="content">
    <p style="color: black"><%= notice %></p>
    <p style="color: red"><%= alert %></p>
  <%= yield %>
  </div>
  <div style="color: black"><%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Without gon, `application.html.erb` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield :title) %></title>
  <%= render 'layouts/stylesheets' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>

  <!-- Begin Analytics -->
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-29558757-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

  </script>
 <!-- End Analytics -->

  <!-- Begin favicon.ico -->
  <%= favicon_link_tag %>
  <!-- End facicon.ico -->

</head>
<body>
  <% unless @home  %>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  <% end %>

  <div id="content">
    <p style="color: black"><%= notice %></p>
    <p style="color: red"><%= alert %></p>
  <%= yield %>
  </div>
  <div style="color: black"><%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All I did was remove the `<%= include_gon %>` line.  When I do this, however, none of my remote forms work anymore.  The callbacks just don't get called.  If I put the `<%= include_gon %>` line back in, the callbacks work again.

Is there a process to remove `gon` from a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a reference to gon in a buried JS file.  For some reason, I wasn't getting an error about gon being undefined, and that error was silently killing the rest of the js interpretation.

Also, I was using slickgrid.  One of the included files with slickgrid seems to be somehow catching the focus of the ajax callbacks